# Angular 1.x - Element appended on directive not rendering

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have this code where I'm trying to append a button to every input element on the page - if I inspect the dom, the button is there, but it is never rendered.

```
  <html>
        <div ng-app="app">
              <label for="input1">input1</label>
              <input name="input1" type="text">
              <br><br><br>
              <label for="input2">input2</label>
              <input name="input2" type="text">
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>


          angular.module('app', [])
          .directive('input', function($compile) {
            return {
              restrict: 'CAE',
              link: Link
            };

            function Link(scope, element, attrs) {

                var elementAppend = '<button>X</button>';
                var a_input = angular.element($compile(elementAppend)(scope));
                element.append(a_input);

            }
          });


          </script>
          </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.append` tries to add the element *inside* the input element, which isn't supported. An `input` element can't have child elements. This restriction comes from HTML, not from AngularJS.

Use `element.after(a_input);` instead to add the button after the input element.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('input', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'CAE',
    link: Link
  };

  function Link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var elementAppend = '<button>X</button>';
    var a_input = angular.element($compile(elementAppend)(scope));
    element.after(a_input);

  }
});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  
  <div id="app">
    <label for="input1">input1</label>
    <input name="input1" type="text">
    <br><br><br>
    <label for="input2">input2</label>
    <input name="input2" type="text">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```